# How do I make my Raspberry Pi act as a wireless USB controller?

Tags: usb, networking, camera

I am trying to control my Canon 550D with the EOS Utility (on my Mac). In theory, this is what I am looking for:

The RPi plugs into the 550D and is connected to a LAN. My Mac is on the same LAN, and is running the EOS Utility. I'd like to make it so the Mac detects the 550D as if it was physically connected to the Mac. I can then use the EOS utility to control all the camera settings (like white balance, shutter speed, focus, start/stop recording, etc).

Is this possible? If so, how?

Comment: You might be able to use gphoto2 to control the camera from the Raspberry Pi, but you would need some way to control gphoto2 remotely from the Mac.

Comment: @Craig Yes, but as far as I know, gphoto2 doesn't support the 550D fully; shutter speed, aperture, etc...

Answer (score 10):

You can share a USB device over the network by installing `usbip` on your RPi. I found a [quick tutorial](http://www.raspberrypi.org/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?p=121691#p121691) on the official Raspberry Pi forum (all credits to secretagent, the OP). I haven't tested the solution by myself.

## On the Raspberry Pi (server)

1. On Raspbian/Debian Wheezy, install `usbip`:

   ```
   $ sudo apt-get install usbip
   ```
2. From now on, the `usbipd` daemon is running when you boot your RPi. Load the host driver:

   ```
   $ sudo modprobe usbip-host
   ```
3. List the USB devices connected to the RPi, and note the device busid you want to share:

   ```
   $ sudo usbip list -l
   ```
4. Add the device you want to share on the network:

   ```
   $ sudo usbip bind --busid <busid>
   ```

   You should see this message:

   ```
   bind device on busid <busid>: complete
   ```

## On the Mac (client)

I don't know if you can install `usbip` on a Mac.

1. Load the driver:

   ```
   $ sudo modprobe vhci-hcd
   ```
2. List the devices shared by your RPi. You should see the same device as in the forth step of the server part. Note the busid.

   ```
   $ usbip --list <the RPi IP address>
   ```
3. Attach the device:

   ```
   $ sudo usbip --attach <the RPi IP address> <busid>
   ```
4. Now, you should be able to see on your Mac the device shared on the RPi:

   ```
   $ lsusb
   ```

To list the virtual USB port status:

```
 $ usbip --port
```

To detach the device:

```
$ sudo usbip --detach <the port in the previous step>
```

Comment: So, in theory, this will be just as if the camera was plugged straight into my Mac?

Comment: @daviesgeek Yes

Comment: Okay...I'm still looking for a Mac version/binary though...doesn't seem like there is one :-/

Answer (score 0):

To make the `modprobe` permanent on the HOST "server" side

run the following command in a ssh (or locally)

```
echo "usbip-host" | sudo tee -a /etc/modules
```

To make the modprobe permanent on the Client side

run the following command in a ssh (or locally)

```
echo "vhci-hcd" | sudo tee -a /etc/modules
```

This will make the needed modules be loaded upon reboot

Comment: Why does exactly answer this the question?

Comment: beause not adding it to the to be loaded modules will put all effort at vain upon reboot of the rpi (wanted or unwanted (powerloss) reboot).

Using this technique to forward a readout-device would be anoying if it reboots, and you cant read the external data anymore.