# How to use a PC to access pendrive that is plugged in pi?

Tags: usb, storage

Is that we can access or see the file in pendrive which is plugged into pi, as a normal storage device in a PC from which the pi is powered?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are using **Raspbian**. If so then you can use `usbip` that is part of the default Raspbian repository. with `apt show usbip` you will get among other things:

> USB/IP is a system for sharing USB devices over the network. To share USB devices between computers with their full functionality, USB/IP encapsulates "USB requests" into IP packets and transmits them between computers.
>
> Original USB device drivers and applications can be used for remote USB devices without any modification of them.  A computer can use remote USB devices as if they were directly attached.
>
> Currently USB/IP provides no access control or encryption.  It should only be used in trusted environments.

How to install it you may find some hints at [How do I make my Raspberry Pi act as a wireless USB controller?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/4436/79866):

Answer (score 0):

No.

You can, however, make the Pi's filesystem accessible over the network, using something like SSHFS, NFS or Samba. You'll find the USB drive in `/media/pi/`.